# Reference a set of subequations with a single label in Lyx

Tags: cross-referencing, lyx, labels, subequations

Using the subequations module, I have created a set of equations labeled 1a, 1b and 1c. I now wish to refer to them collectively as (1) in subsequent text. Here's my code copied from the LyX file:

```
\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Flex Subequations
\label{eq:ReferToAll}
status open


\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Formula 
\begin{align}
w_{1} & =1\label{eq:Ref1}\\
w_{2} & =2\label{eq:Ref2}\\
w_{3} & =3\label{eq:Ref3}
\end{align}

\end_inset

\end_layout
```

I can refer to these equations as (1a) - (1c) using Ref1 and Ref3. That's easy. But I want to refer to the three equations collectively as (1) and I'm having trouble doing so.

Following a suggestion I found on the web, I added the label {eq:ReferToAll} just after Subequations using a text editor (I couldn't figure out how to add it in LyX) but I don't see ReferToAll in the list of available references when I try and insert a cross-reference.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I achieve my goal in LyX?

Thanks in advance

Thomas Philips

Comment: The way you added the label `\label{eq:ReferToAll}` should work. Is the code you provided copied directly from the LaTeX source panel?

Comment: Use the `subsequations` environment in `amsmath`.

Comment: It is copied from the text file - oddly enough I don't see the ReferToAll reference when I view the code in the LaTeX source panel in LyX

Comment: Also, I have loaded amsmath, but don't see anything to do with subequations (I can add AMS align environments for example without any problem)

Answer (score 1):

Solved it! The secret is to place the cursor *inside* the subequation box but before any of the subequations. I could then insert an equation label which refers to the entire equation. The TeX code looks like this

```
\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Flex Subequations
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset CommandInset label
LatexCommand label
name "eq: ReferToAll"

\end_inset


\begin_inset Formula 
\begin{align}
w_{1} & =1\label{eq:Ref1}\\
w_{2} & =2\label{eq:Ref2}\\
w_{3} & =3\label{eq:Ref3}
\end{align}

\end_inset

\end_layout
```

So my earlier attempt was missing a few lines of needed code (\begin_inset CommandInset label etc. etc.).

Once I realized that I had to poke delicately around the subequation for just the right spot to insert the label for the overall equation, I was able to get it to work.

Thomas Philips